# Not able to use Mule Session variable in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, mule

I have a mule flow wherein the payload is something like,

```
<Day>
<Sunday>1</Sunday>
<Tuesday>5</Tuesday>
<Thursday>10</Thursday>
<Saturday>15</Saturday>
</Day>
```

Then I set a session variable depending on which day it is to something like,

```
<set-session-variable variableName="SelectedDay" value="Sunday" doc:name="Save Day "/>
```

Now I need to use this session variable to get the value inside the node 'Sunday', ie 1.

Im thinking something like

```
 #[xpath://(sessionVars['SelectedDay'])]
```

The value of SelectedDay can be any of the other days, depending on other factors.

I can't seem to get the xpath expressions work and flow is returning this exception.

Failed to evaluate XPath expression: "#[xpath://(sessionVars['SelectedDay'])] (org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException)
  org.mule.module.xml.expression.AbstractXPathExpressionEvaluator:144 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleRuntimeException.html)

Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xpath, the expression is:

```
#[xpath('//Day/' + sessionVars.SelectedDay).text]
```

Using xpath3, the expression is:

```
#[xpath3('//Day/' + sessionVars.SelectedDay)]
```

Comment: Fine. If it works then you can mark as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `#[xpath://(#[sessionVars['SelectedDay']])]` and see if it works

If it doesn't then you can also try `#[xpath://(#[sessionVars.SelectedDay])]`